# keeps fetching the old json data?

Tags: json, react-native, fetch

I'm trying to fetch a json file from a https link however, no matter what link a give the result does not change!?

I validated all the json files. in case they had an error.
the responseData stays the same, and even when I force the data to change by instead returning responseData returning a json manually written; it changes right back to the old json data that just doesnt change when I return responseData back.
And the responseData that I requested to be be posted on the console gives the wrong information
The url given is correct.
but the output doesnt correspond to the data when I fill the link in the internetbrowser.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        connected: false,
    }
    this.init = this.init.bind(this);
    this.getJson = this.getJson.bind(this);
    this.updateVisited = this.updateVisited.bind(this);
}

    init = async ({json})=>{
    if(json==null){
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('database', "");
        alert('error occured');
    } else {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('database', JSON.stringify(json));
        this.setState({
            connected: true
        });
    }
}

getJson = async ()=>{
    var url = await AsyncStorage.getItem("database_url");
    console.log(url);
    return fetch(url,
    {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseData => {
        this.updateVisited(url);
        console.log(responseData);
        return responseData;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        alert('Could not connect!');
        return null;
    })
}

connect = async ({url})=>{
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("database_url", url);
    this.getJson().then(json => this.init({json}));
}
```

---

```
"a_json": [{"name": "greg"}]
"test": [{"name": "sheldon"}]
"temp": [{"name": "bob"}]
```

when the url points to the json test it gives bob expecting sheldon
when the url points to the json temp it gives bob expecting bob
when the url points to the json a_json it gives bob expecting greg
when returning a json without trying to fetch it from the internet at the place of responseData; it gives the expecting value

If you need more information, feel free to ask.
Thank you for your time reading my question.

Comment: Try changing cache control to `no-cache` in the headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the `Cache-Control`.
I added `'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'` to the header of the fetch, which fixed the problem!

This was pointed out by @Pritish Vaidya in the comments